# simple check function in solidity

Tags: solidity

i just want to check whether the address is whitelisted or not that is set in the whiteLister function.

code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

contract minter{


    function whiteLister( address _user) public{

    }

    function checkWhhiteListed(address user) public view returns (bool){

    )

}
```

Comment: How are you whitelisting the addresses? Are you using a mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a whitelist, you must extend the functionality of your existing code from what you posted above. In terms of whitelisting you need to create a `mapping`, that stores the whitelisted addresses.

Then make the contract deployer the `owner` in constructor.
The owner can whitelist users with `whitelistUser` and you can check if someone is verified with a function like `checkIfUserWhitelisted`. As whitelisted address you can also call `doSomethingAsWhitelisted` and return true.

See below code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Whitelist {

    // contract owner
    address owner;  

    // store whitelisted addresses 
    // in mapping from address => true/false
    mapping(address => bool) whitelisted;

    // function modifier
    // passes if user is owner
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "must be owner.");
        _;
    }

    // function modifier
    // passes if user is whitelisted
    modifier onlyWhitelisted() {
        require(whitelisted[msg.sender], "You need to be whitelisted");
        _;
    }

    // make contract creator the owner
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // function to whitelist
    // a user by address if msg.sender == owner
    function whitelistUser(address _user) external onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = true;
    }

    // function to check for
    // whitelisting status
    function checkIfUserWhitelisted(address _user) external view returns(bool) {
        bool userIsWhitelisted = whitelisted[_user];
        return userIsWhitelisted;
    }

    // function that can only
    // executed as whitelisted user
    function doSomethingAsWhitelisted() external view onlyWhitelisted returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```